# javascript reposition overflow table scroll position

Tags: javascript, css, dom, google-chrome-devtools, addeventlistener

I am drawing a table using a function after data is received from a GET request.
After I draw the table, I want to hold the scroll position relative to the previous table that was there before (all tables have `overflow:auto;`).

The way I overcome this problem is as follows:

1. listen to the scroll
2. store the scroll position in sessionStorage
3. After the new table is drawn, I use `.scrolLeft = sessionStorage.getItem('PosY')`

This works fine as it does what I want it to do, but I get the following from Chrome Dev.

`[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 51ms`

I understand why I get this from Chrome Dev. but I want to know if there is another way to do this that will not give me this `[Violation]`

I have looked into listening to the DOM and repositioning upon changes, but this gives the same `[Violation]`

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, especially if there is some simple CSS.

No jQuery OR other Libraries, please.

Comment: Might be a timing thing - have you tried throwing your scroll position command in a `setTimeout`?

Comment: Thank YOU. This was also helpful https://yonatankra.com/layout-reflow/